# How to alter/extend the type of a property?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Given the following ambient type definition of a javascript library (that I cannot change):

```
// a library with typings I cannot change
interface Widget {
    name: string;
}
interface Event {
    widget: Widget;
}

declare function addListener(listener: (event: Event) => void):void;
declare function showWidget(renderFn: (widget: Widget) => void): void;
```

And there is an extension module to that javascript library that enhances `event.widget` (but not Widget in general) by something like this;

```
interface EnhancedWidget {
    displayName: string;
}
function eventExtender(event:Event) {
    (event.widget as any).displaName = '....';
}
```

Now I want to enhance `Event` with this definition, but typescript complains

```
interface Event {
    widget: Widget & EnhancedWidget;
}
```

Adding new properties is allowed but changing the type of a property is not allowed. But this is what can happen in reality. I wonder if there is a way to express this in typescript.

At the end I want to use the new `displayName` property of `event.widget`:

```
addListener( event => console.log(event.widget.displaName) )
```

But this should complain (because widget is not enhanced in this context):

```
showWidget(widget => console.log(event.displaName))
```

Therefore extending `Widget` like this is **not** an option:

```
// does not work, because it will enhance all Widget usages and
// not just in the specific context
interface Widget {
    displayName: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about having these:

```
interface EnhancedWidget extends Widget {
    displayName: string;
}
interface EnhancedEvent extends Event {
    widget: EnhancedWidget;
}
```

And then adding another signature for `addListener`:

```
declare function addListener(listener: (event: EnhancedEvent) => void):void;
```

This will still fail:

```
addListener(event => console.log(event.widget.displayName));
```

With:

> Property 'displayName' does not exist on type 'Widget'

But this will work:

```
addListener((event: EnhancedEvent) => console.log(event.widget.displayName))
```

Comment: The point is, I don't have control over the library (the first coding block). There are lots of `addListener` like functions in that library and I don't want to re-write the entire typings for the external library.

Comment: Ah, I see how this works in that particular case. However, I would have to know to use `EnhancedEvent` in the callback. I am looking for a way that code completion would tell me that `event.widget` now has new attributes.

Comment: I don't think that it's possible. Using `EnhancedEvent` is just normal polymorphism. It makes sense to use a new type because you are indeed not changing all instance of events/widgets, just the ones who got "enhanced".